# How to increment a variable contained within a class in python from outside of its class?

Tags: python

I have a fairly simple python question, as I am pretty new to the language. I started writing a quick program just for practice, but have now become frustrated because I cannot get it to work.

```
import random
import sys


class Meta:
    turncounter = 1


class Enemy:
    life = 10
    wis = 1
    str = 3

def heal(self):
    healscore = self.wis + random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
    self.life += healscore
    print "Enemy healed for " + str(healscore) + ".\n"
    self.checklife()
    Meta.turncounter += 1

def attack(self, player):
    damage = self.str + random.randrange(1, 5, 1)
    player.life -= damage
    print "You took " + str(damage) + " damage.\n"
    Player.checklife(player)
    Meta.turncounter += 1

def checklife(self):
    if self.life <= 0:
        print "The enemy is dead.\n"
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "Enemy's HP: " + str(self.life) + ".\n"


class Player:
    life = 50
    wis = 3
    str = 5

def heal(self):
    healscore = self.wis + random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
    self.life += healscore
    print "You healed for " + str(healscore) + ".\n"
    Meta.turncounter += 1

def attack(self, enemy):
    damage = self.str + random.randrange(1, 5, 1)
    enemy.life -= damage
    print "You did " + str(damage) + " damage.\n"
    Enemy.checklife(enemy)
    Meta.turncounter += 1

def checklife(self):
    if self.life <= 0:
        sys.exit("You died!")
    else:
        print "HP: " + str(self.life) + ".\n"

paladin = Player()
hollow = Enemy()
turnmeta = Meta.turncounter % 2
move = random.randrange(1, 3, 1)

print turnmeta
print move

while turnmeta == 0:
    if move == 1 and paladin.life <= 10:
        paladin.heal()
        print turnmeta
    elif move != 0 or (move == 1 and hollow.life > 15):
        paladin.attack(hollow)
        print turnmeta

while turnmeta > 0:
    if move == 1 and hollow.life <= 15:
        print turnmeta
    elif move != 0 or (move == 1 and hollow.life > 15):
        hollow.attack(paladin)
        print turnmeta
```

As you can see, this program isn't particularly complex; it is just meant to be something to generally understand python syntax and loops and such. For some reason, whenever I run the program, instead of the turncounter incrementing and the paladin / hollow having a back and forth, the turncounter stays locked in at 1, causing the hollow to attack until the paladin dies, instantly ending the program.

Comment: Is the indentation correct in your question?  The class methods don't appear to be indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your while-loop is relying on `turnmeta`, which doesn't change when you increment `Meta.turncounter` in your class methods.

Notice:

```
>>> class Meta(object):
...    turncounter = 0
... 
>>> turnmeta = Meta.turncounter
>>> turnmeta
0
>>> Meta.turncounter += 1
>>> turnmeta
0
>>> Meta.turncounter
1
```

Just use `Meta.turncounter`.

That being said, your design, which relies heavily on class attributes, is not good design, and skimming over your code I don't think you are doing what you think you are doing. Python class definitions are different from Java.

You need to define instance attributes inside of an `__init__` method (or any other method) using `self.attribute`, and  not in the class namespace, as you have done in your class definitions.

Read the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop never ends if `move == 1` because the value of the variable `turnmeta` is never changed and is always 1 and the variable 'move` is always 1.

You need to give them a new value in your loops: `turnmeta = Meta.turncounter % 2` and `move = random.randrange(1, 3, 1)` if I understand your program correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`turnmeta` is the result of your calculation `Meta.turncounter % 2`.

It doesn't make any reference to your `Meta.turncounter` anymore.

You should reassign the turnmeta after each turns.